# How to call/submit Form from another page in custom module?

Tags: 8, hooks

I would like to set cron function in my custom module. I have created one form which is called with submit button from UI. Now I would like to submit/call that form from another page (.module file) where I have written my hook_cron function, how it would be possible?

In Drupal 7, I use

```
$form_state['values'] = "";
drupal_form_submit('customfeedimport_main_pagecallback_submit', $form_state);
```

But I am new to Drupal 8, so how to perform this cron thing in Drupal 8?

Also what should be included in the namespace, use?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the [FormBuilder::submitForm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AsubmitForm/8.4.x) function.

To register a new user (taken from the docs):

```
// register a new user
$form_state = new FormState();
$values['name'] = 'robo-user';
$values['mail'] = 'robouser@example.com';
$values['pass']['pass1'] = 'password';
$values['pass']['pass2'] = 'password';
$values['op'] = t('Create new account');
$form_state->setValues($values);
\Drupal::formBuilder()->submitForm('user_register_form', $form_state);
```

You might have to include the namespace for the [FormState](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/class/FormState/8.4.x) class before this code if not done already.

Comment: Hello AjitS, I have tried but it's giving me an error. Can you please provide me the full code with a namespace, so I can get know better.